# Launch Agent and "CGSDeviceSynchronize: Invalid device window"

Tags: macos, cocoa, launch-agent

I have created an OSX App which runs as a LaunchAgent. It has a Status Menu.  After installation if I logout and login again, the Status Menu doesn't appear. The app appears in the activity monitor though. I noticed that the Main Xib itself is not getting loaded. And from the console, i see the following logs:

```
23/04/14 4:52:37.543 pm MyApp Agent[24861]: CGSDeviceGetGeometry: Invalid device window
23/04/14 4:52:37.544 pm MyApp Agent[24861]: CGSDeviceGetGeometry: Invalid device window
23/04/14 4:52:37.544 pm MyApp Agent[24861]: CGSDeviceSynchronize: Invalid device window
```

I am unable to replicate it always. But whenever the issue occurs, I seem to be getting the above logs.